# How to create a stacked area plot of individuals cumulative contributions over time?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, seaborn

Given a set of datapoints of individuals' sales figures, I'm trying to create a stacked area graph showing total sales over time, split by the contribution of the individual salespeople.

```
import datetime
import random
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = []
for _ in range(100):
    name = random.choice(['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'Dave', 'Eve'])
    date = datetime.date(2020,1,1) + datetime.timedelta(days=random.randint(0,20))
    sales = random.randint(0,20)
    data.append((name,date,sales))

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Date', 'Sales'])\
    .set_index('Date')\
    .sort_values('Date')
df['Total Sales']= df['Sales'].cumsum()
df['Total Sales by person'] = df.groupby('Name')['Sales'].cumsum()
```

I've got almost there with two different approaches, but can't see how to complete it.  Can anyone help, or suggest an alternate approach?

Approach 1: use seaborn to do a lineplot.  Simple and pretty, but I can't get it to stack

```
sns.lineplot(data=df, x='Date', y='Total Sales by person', hue='Name')
plt.show()
```

[image: Seaborn lineplot]

Approach 2: turn the data into a pivot table, then use pandas area plot.  It stacks properly on the days when every salesperson has sold something, but every 'NaN' causes problems.

```
pt = pd.pivot_table(df, columns=['Name'], index=['Date'], values=['Total Sales by person'])
pt.plot.area()
plt.show()
```

```
>>> pt.head(10)
           Total Sales by person                               
Name                       Alice    Bob       Carol  Dave   Eve
Date                                                           
2020-01-01                   NaN   11.0   15.000000  11.0   3.0
2020-01-03                   NaN    NaN   34.000000  20.0   NaN
2020-01-04                   NaN   34.0   52.000000  28.0   NaN
2020-01-05                  19.0   57.0         NaN   NaN  15.0
2020-01-06                  22.0   72.5         NaN  36.0  34.0
2020-01-07                   NaN    NaN   52.000000  50.0  35.0
2020-01-08                  34.0    NaN   62.500000   NaN  51.0
2020-01-09                  53.0   92.0   80.000000  64.5  60.0
2020-01-10                  53.0  107.5   95.666667  75.0   NaN
2020-01-11                   NaN  120.0  136.666667  77.0  67.0
```

[image: Pandas Area Plot]

Any bright ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it.  I needed to create the pivot table first with just the sales data, fill any missing values with 0, THEN add the cumulative sum.  Final code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Date', 'Sales'])\
    .set_index('Date')\
    .sort_values('Date')

pt = pd.pivot_table(df, columns=['Name'], index=['Date'], values=['Sales'], fill_value=0)
pt = pt.cumsum()
pt.plot.area()
plt.show()
```

[image: MatPlotLib stacked plot]